# why is my collector in discord.js not responding to the reply?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

The bot asks the question and gives the result if the answer isn't given in the certain amount of time mentioned. Problem is even if the answer is given the bot doesn't read it and say that it is correct.

```js
const item = quiz[Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.length)];
const filter = (response) => {
    return item.answers.some((answer) => answer.toLowerCase() === response.content.toLowerCase());
};

interaction.reply({ content: item.question, fetchReply: true }).then(() => {
    interaction.channel
        .awaitMessages({ filter, max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ["time"] })
        .then((collected) => {
            interaction.followUp(`${collected.first().author} got the correct answer!`);
        })
        .catch((collected) => {
            interaction.followUp("Looks like nobody got the answer this time.");
        });
});
```

Comment: What intents have you enabled?

Comment: saw this and i realised where i goofed up. thanks brodie, it works now <3

Comment: Feel free to add an answer below and explain what intents you needed or what else fixed the issue. This way others who find this question can fix their issues too.